# Autokey - What windows application is the Closest Alternative?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, automation

In Ubuntu, I use autokey-qt to associate both (1) hot-keys and (2) typed-abbreviations to automate typing and initiate python scripts that modify selected text:
sudo apt-get install autokey-qt

What would be the closest open source match for this application in the Windows environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for Windows is free and does this kind of automation.